# Is there a way to get the 'is skos:broader of' of an entity from DBPedia using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

Basically, I'm trying to get the 'subclasses' of this entity. For example:

[image: DBpedia Egyptian film actors]

I tried using --

```
select ?p1 where {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Norwegian_silent_film_actors> skos:narrower ?p1 .
}
```

-- and --

```
select ?p1 where {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Norwegian_silent_film_actors> rdfs:subclass ?p1 .
}
```

-- but since that's not actually its predicate, it doesn't work. Both actually return just the entity itself if a `*` is added after the predicate.

Is there any way of getting those objects?

Comment: I suggest you change the picture to show `Norwegian_silent_film_actors`, or changing your tests to use `Egyptian_film_actors`. Mixing things as you have is likely to cause confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember that `is skos:broader of` relations are inverse `skos:broader` relations -- which *imply* but do not necessarily indicate the presence of `skos:narrower` statements.  DBpedia doesn't have every explicit statement that might be inferred from what's there, and inference rules are not active by default.

You can use the explicit statements that do exist with queries like this, which uses the property path `+` for one-or-more `skos:broader` relationships --

```
select ?p1 
where 
  {
    ?p1  
       skos:broader+
         <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Norwegian_silent_film_actors> 
  }
```

-- or this, which uses the property path `^` to reverse the relationship --

```
select ?p1 
where 
  {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Norwegian_silent_film_actors>
       ^skos:broader*
          ?p1
  }
```

This is a place where [inference rules](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK) might well be brought to bear. Unfortunately, there are no predefined inference rules relating `skos:broader` and `skos:narrower`, and this public endpoint does not accept ad-hoc rule additions.  You could create some on a personal endpoint, whether [pre-built and pre-populated with DBpedia in the cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK) or otherwise.